# Как мне сделать название переменной как у строки

Tags: python

Как мне сделать название переменной как у строки
например есть строка string='name' и чтоб было название у переменной как у string то есть название будет name

Comment: Если возникла такая потребность, то скорее всего вы что-то делаете неправильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй globals вот так globals()[string]=

Answer (score 2):

Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите, но я могу предложить вот такой вариант решения

`name = "name"`

Comment: это как что то я не понимаю

Comment: @Stepan, переменной можно давать любое имя. Например, есть строка, я могу её назвать `name` или `noname`. Имя переменной может быть почти любое слово на английском языке

Comment: на русском тоже

Comment: про русский язык я не знал. Но если ты будешь переменные называть по русски, то придётся при работе всё время переключаться с одного языка на другой, потому что питон надо писать на англ., а переменный на русс. и всё время туда - сюда, туда - сюда. Это не очень удобно в ежедневной работе

Comment: Я знаю я это почти не использую кстати так можно и с функциями